# What is wrong with I_drain?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, pspice, powermosfet

After adding an inductive load at the switching node of the half bridge circuit, the drain current keeps increasing. Why is this so? What have I done wrong in the circuit? I first tried to put L,C,R in the load side by caluclating like in a synchronous buck chopper, but that was not converging for DC Bus 100 V or DC bus 200 V. I am first trying to simulate at frequency = 100kHz or 200kHz. Please suggest a method to calculate the load inductor value to be added here. My objective is to study the active clamping, so for that I need to first simulate a self-turn on like phenomenon, i.e the "glitch" in the VGS waveform.
MOSFET used is [SCT3160KL](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/sic/mosfet/sct3160kl-e.pdf).
[image: Idrain]

[image: circuit]

Also, in the circuit I had downloaded from TI website had that 10nF capacitance (C9) connected between Gate and Emitter of the IGBT in their circuit, which I replaced with my MOSFET. What is its purpose? I removed it and simulated but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Which simulator are you working with?

Comment: OrCad-Pspice software